# SBS 2008 Email distribution list - not working with external email

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I created an email distribution list through the SBS Console and checked the option to make it available to people outside the organization.

Whenever I try to send from an external address to the email address of the distribution group I get the ''550 no such person at this address'

I'm using this group to have all members receive the email if someone sends it to the group email.

Comment: Does the DG have a valid email address? If so, is this the email address you're sending to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating another distro group to ensure it's not something bad about the specific group you're testing?  In other words, is it all new distro groups you create or just this one?  If just this one, you should delete and recreate.

Do you have any devices in front of Exchange is is it direct Internet to Exchange SMTP IP?  If so you will want to check those first.

Lastly look at the SMTP tab to ensure the SMTP address is the same.  When creating Exchange distro groups in GUI it sometimes adds numbers to SMTP address if there is another user/group using that email address.